# Кратковременные прерывания перерисовки теста в методе onDraw()

Tags: android

В переопределенном мной методе `onDraw()` я разместил код прорисовки текста.

Этот код перерисовывает текст после изменения координат и вызова `invalidate()` в методе `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`.

Во время перерисовки (текст перемещается по экрану) наблюдаются кратковременные непериодические замирания движения текста. Очень похоже на **системное прерывание** (понятие из assembler) во время выполнения моего кода.

Суть вопроса такова: существует ли в Android-программировании какие-нибудь методы для обеспечения непрерываемости фрагмента моего кода?

Answer (score 2):

Это больше похоже на то, что ваш код в `onDraw` не оптимизирован. Почитайте [Optimizing the View](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/custom-views/optimizing-view.html).

Там не должно быть ничего тяжёлого. Например, если вы там создаёте объекты, аллокации проводите, вынесите их из `onDraw`. Так же уменьшите количество вызовов `onDraw`. А он в свою очередь вызывается каждый раз, когда вы вызываете `invalidate()`, так что, постарайтесь вызывать его пореже.

Или же проблема в большой вложенности `ViewGroup` слоёв.